# "Prove that 98765432 is not the square of an integer" vs "Deduce that 1234567 is not a perfect square"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

"Prove that 98765432 is not the square of an integer" and "Deduce that 1234567 is not a perfect square" are the two statements that my textbook (An Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning by P. Eccles) covers. However, I notice there's a contradiction when I apply their methods in a swapped manner, which I can't seem to figure out.

For simplicity, let's call the proof of the first statement, "Prove that 98765432 is not the square of an integer", **Proof 1**, and the proof of the second statement, "Deduce that 1234567 is not a perfect square", **Proof 2**.

Proving that $98765432$ is not the square of an integer:

> **Proof 1:**
>   Let $n = 98765432$
>
> *Proposition 15.2.3* states, "If n is a perfect square (i.e. the square of an integer) then $n = 3q$ or $n = 3q + 1$ for some integer, $q$".
>
> $98,765,432 = 3q + 2$ where $q = 32,921,810$
>
> Thus, we have shown that $98765432$ is not a perfect square, by *Proposition 15.2.3*
>
> $Q.E.D.$

Then, in another example problem, the book proves the statement "If n is a perfect square, then n = 4q or n = 4q + 1 for some integer, q." to be valid. Then, the author deduces that 1234567 is not a perfect square as follows:

> **Proof 2:**
>   Let $n = 1234567$
>
> $1,234,567 = 4q + 3$ where $q = 308,641$
>
> Since $1234567$ does not equal $4q$ or $4q + 1$, it is not a perfect square.
>   Thus, we have deduced $1234567$ is not a perfect square.
>
> $Q.E.D.$

I do comprehend how he used a derivation of the division theorem to prove these statements. What I can't wrap my head around is when I switch the logic used for the two proofs, I theorize that it should work the same way. However, it doesn't and I would like to know why. Moreover, when I use Proposition 15.2.3 ("If n is a perfect square (i.e. the square of an integer) then $n = 3q$ or $n = 3q + 1$ for some integer, $q$.) on the number $n = 1234567$, I get the following:

> **Proof 1 (revised):**
>   Let $n = 1234567$ *Notice the "revision" is that I am using the number n from **Proof 2** instead
>
> $1,234,567 = 3q + 1$ where $q = 411,522$
>
> <s>Thus, we have shown that 1234567 is not a perfect square, by *Proposition 15.2.3*</s>
>
> We cannot deduce by *Proposition 15.2.3* that $1,234,567$ is not the sqaure of an integer since $1,234,567 = 3q + 1$
>
> $Q.E.D.$

Similarly, I did the same with **Proof 2** as follows:

> **Proof 2 (revised):**
>   Let $n = 98765432$ *Note: the revision here is this n is the n from **Proof 1 ** instead
>
> $98,765,432 = 4q $ where $q = 308,641$
>
> <s>Thus, we have deduced 98765432 is not a perfect square.</s>
>
> Since $1234567$ does equal $4q$ or $4q + 1$, it cannot be deduced that n is a perfect square.
>
> $Q.E.D.$

Comment: I am not sure I understand the underlying question fully, but suffice to say that lack of proof is not disproof and lack of disproof is not proof.  Trying to prove $1234567$ is not a perfect square using a modulo 3 argument does not work since $1234567\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ which puts it into the realm of "*feasibly still a square or not a square*."  In general when approaching a problem like this, either find an argument that shows without a doubt it is a square or is not a square and if the test is inconclusive search for another test to use.

Comment: If you have problem perceiving some logic, you may take an easier example to avoid unnecessary disturbance. In this situation, let's consider: Thm 1. If $x=0$ then $x\ge 0$; Thm 2. If $x=2$ then $x\le 2$. Now how would you use those two theorems to prove $-1\ne 0$ and $1\ne 0$?

Comment: The possible tests you can use for proving something is not a square is more than just modulo3 and modulo 4 tests., you could do for example a modulo 10 test: The possible final digits for square numbers are $0,1,4,5,6,9$ so if the final digit happens to be a $2,3,7,8$ we know immediately that it cannot be a square.  Ironically, the modulo 10 test works for both of your example numbers to prove that they are both not squares.  In general, you can design a test for modulo $n$ for any $n$ by looking at the possible values of $x^2$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you! I understand where my misconception lies now. I assumed we were limited to the modulo 3 and modulo 4 cases but I get that it is simply one of many tools that can be utilized to show whether a certain number is a perfect square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that IF $n$ is a perfect square, THEN $n=3q$ or $n=3q+1$ for some $q$. This theorem is false the other way around.

What I'm saying is, if $n$ is not a perfect square, then we can still have $n=3q$ or $n=3q+1$.

Basically it comes down to logic. "If $A$, then $B$" is not the same as "If not $A$, then not $B$", but it is the same as "If not $B$, then not $A$". If it rains, I get wet. If I get wet, it doesn't have to rain - I could be in the shower. But if I don't get wet, we know for sure that it doesn't rain.

This is why you can use the theorem

> if $n$ is a perfect square, then $n=3q$ or $n=3q+1$ for some $q$.

To say

> if not $n=3q$ or $n=3q+1$ for some $q$, then not $n$ is a perfect square.

which in normal words would be

> if $n\neq3q$ or $n\neq3q+1$ for all $q$, then $n$ is not a perfect square.

So in your first example, $98765432$ is not of the form $98765432=3q$ and also not of the form $98765432=3q+1$, thus, it cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: The way you wrote your contrapositive statement in the second quoteblock seems off.  Recommend changing to be "If $n\neq 3q$ and $n\neq 3q+1$ *for all* $q$ then..."

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out the theorems only says that squares must fulfill these properties, but it does **not** say that all numbers fulfilling these properties are squares.

For example we have for $q=2$ that neither $6=3q$ nor $7=3q+1$ is a square. Similarily we have for $q=3$ that neither $12=4q$ nor $13=4q+1$ is a square.

The numbers $12$ and $13$ shows that neither of these criteria are required to work for deciding if they are squares. They both fulfill both requirements that there's an $q=4$ such that $12=3q$ or $13=3q+1$ and there's an $q=3$ such that $12=4q$ and $13=4q+1$.

The way to be guaranteed to decide is to take "integer square root". For example $\sqrt{98765432} = 9938.079895\cdots$. Maybe this isn't considered "mathematical" but we have that $9938^2 = 98763844 < 98765432 < 98783721 = 9939^2$ then one complete that for any other $r\in\mathbb N$ (than $9938$ or $9939$) we have either that $r<9938$ which means that $r^2 < 9938^2$ or $r>9939$ which means $r^2 > 9939^2$ - that is $r^2 \ne 9875432$.